# Puppeteer browser loses connection after Windows sleep

Tags: node.js, windows, browser, puppeteer, sleep

In windows 10 64 bit, I launch the Chrome browser:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, args: [`--window-size=500,750`], defaultViewport: null }); // viewport matches windows size
page = await browser.newPage();
```

This is all fine until the PC sleeps and is then woken whereupon the browser no longer works and the following call returns false:

```
await browser.isConnected(); // returns false
```

The browser and page are still visibly there, look fine, and I can press F5 and the page refreshes. How do I reconnect my Puppeteer program to that I can avoid having to log back into the website. Worth saying that "await browser.close()" successfully closes the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `pipe: true` to prevent websocket disconnected

set https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions.pipe